# How to update data in Onsen UI (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I am working in an app with onsen ui + phonegap.
Then I have a page that user click to favorite the post.
This page has the last 4 photos of people who favorited the post recently.
Then I already add the class "active" to button favorite.
But now the problem: How can I update data of last 4 people who favorited the post to appear the user photo? This data is in an angular service.
And this is how I get it in template:

`<ons-col ng-repeat="pe in people | limitTo: 4">`

Does someone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: I think we need some more code in order to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using `ons-navigator`. If you are `pop`ing a page, the previous page would not be created from scratch.

If you need to recreate the previous page, pass `{refresh: true}` as a parameter to the `nav.popPage`.

```
nav.popPage({refresh: true});
```